# Segmentation Fault - linked lists (UNIX)

Tags: c, unix, linked-list, pthreads, semaphore

I'm trying to understand why i'm receiving a segmentation fault.

I have a linked list 'head' with prev and next pointers and i'm trying to delete a specific node in the list. The specific node's address is held by 'ptr'.
I've attached an image showing the debugger, 
the following code gives me segmentation fault:
(I'm showing only what's relevant)

```
void someFunc(char str[], int atmSN){


/*some code */ 

switch(ch){    /// ch is char

/* some code */

case 'Q':       
    if (ptr == head){                   // if ptr head of linked list
        head = head->next;
        if (head != NULL)
            head->prev = NULL;
    }
    else{
        ptr->prev->next = ptr->next;
        if (ptr->next != NULL)  // if ptr is not last
            ptr->next->prev = ptr->prev;
    }

    free(ptr);
break;

/*some code */
```

[debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6xfj.png)

My code is using multi-threads, so perhaps another thread is writing to the specific node while the current thread is trying to delete it.
In my task I have to implement semaphores as well, But does this can give us a segmentation fault?

Correct me if i'm wrong: segmentation fault happens when we try to reach a memory which does "not exist"?

If someone could enlighten me, I would be grateful.

EDIT: debugger info:

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff5ff9700 (LWP 3350)]
0x00000000004011cb in operation (str=0x7ffff5ff8e00 "Q 1111 1111", atmSN=3)
    at hw4.c:175
175                     ptr->prev->next = ptr->next;
```

Comment: `switch(char ch)` I sure that it doesn't compile. Post a true [mcve]. And don't post image, copy and paste the text of the console !

Comment: the entire code is 500 lines long, so char ch was only to show ch is a char. If it wouldn't compile i wouldn't be able to post you a screenshot of the dubbuger.

Comment: That doesn't change anything about what I said.

Comment: A debugger will easily provide information where exactly is the segmentation fault happening. Is it happening when you try to delete the head, or in other cases?

Comment: I know. the debugger says it happens in " ptr->prev->next = ptr->next;"
but i don't see why ?

Comment: @Rom posting fictitious code like `switch(char ch)` which you hope will help, does not help your case. Who knows what other fictions there are and not *actual code*?

Comment: why do you care about the ch? it's clearly not the problem. the debugger says there is segmentation fault in " ptr->prev->next = ptr->next" line

Comment: The reason I care is because it shows this is not "your code". Post exact code, not "something like my code", and the MCVE should do just that. You are in no position to know what is relevant, or you would not be asking.

Comment: @Rom Maybe because we know better than you what we need to solve your problem than you ? How do you believe that we could know what is the error(or the hundred of errors) that your true program have ? You need to **READ** [ask] **AND** [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My code is using multi-thread

Multi-threaded environments must make you consider *lock context*, such as mutexes or semaphores. Any time you have more than one thread of execution running simultaneously (HyperThreading, multi-core, or pre-emptive multithreading on single core systems), consider that the *thread of execution* can change *at any moment*. It's up to you to *guard* the logic to ensure that you don't blow off your own foot.

So, consider the following scenarios:

- You have two threads, T1 and T2. You have a two-node linked list.
- T1 calls *your code* and sees `(ptr == head)`, and moves along.
- Context switch!
- T2 calls *your code* and sees `(ptr == head)`, and moves along.
- T2 sets `head = head->next`
- T2 checks `if (head != NULL)`, sees it's *not NULL*.
- Context switch!
- T1 sets `head = head->next`

What do you think T1 assigns to `head`? Continuing:

- Context switch!
- T2 assigns `head->prev = NULL`. It just dereferenced `head` which was assigned by `T1`. What do you think happens?

Imagine this kind of context switching for *all* of your logic flow. How do you *guard* against it?

The answer to this question is generally well-understood and often asked (and frequently answered). You should be able to find the answers you seek from here.

Comment: Without a MCVE (which @Stargateur already asked for), it would be impossible for me to say definitively. But, yes, that's my initial guess.

Comment: @Rom: do you know that the linked list code works correctly in a single-threaded environment?  If not, make it work correctly when single-threaded.  Get the memory allocation and so on correct first.  Then protect it for use in a multi-threaded environment, applying appropriate mutexes or other synchronization control operations (possibly even a semaphore, though I think mutexes are probably sufficient if you're careful).  You need to consider how much parallelism you need — do you need two separate threads to be able to access the same list at the same time?  It's easier if you don't.